# How to use a row number variable to create a cell reference string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

I have a variable called Number which will be a row's number.
I want to use `getRange(N+number)`.
For example if I have `Number=5`, I will have `getRange("N5")`.
I don't know how to make this string

Answer (score 0):

## Code

```
function myfunction(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var number = 5;
  var range = sheet.getRange('N' + number);
  var Logger.log('%s value: %s','N'+ number,range.getValue());
}
```

## Explanation

You could use `+` to concatenate a number to a string, the result is a string.